# Temporarily Stop IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I have read the countless articles on how to disable IntelliSense completely but that is not what I what to do (for someone with a memory like mine it can be useful!).

What I want to do is stop it popping up when I am doing something repetitive and I don't need it.  A simple example is (although not the greatest as you wouldn't do this but bear with the idea)...

I have 10 columns in a database table and want to populate a class:

```
response.MyValues = new MyClass
{
        Value1 = dr["Value1"].ToString(),
        Value2 = dr["Value2"].ToString(),
        Value3 = dr["Value3"].ToString(),
        Value4 = dr["Value4"].ToString(),
        Value5 = dr["Value5"].ToString(),
        Value6 = dr["Value6"].ToString(),
        Value7 = dr["Value7"].ToString(),
        Value8 = dr["Value8"].ToString(),
        Value9 = dr["Value9"].ToString(),
        Value10 = dr["Value10"].ToString()
};
```

So I write the first `Value1 = dr["Value1"].ToString(),` then copy and paste it another 9 times:

```
response.MyValues = new MyClass
{
        Value1 = dr["Value1"].ToString(),
        Value1 = dr["Value1"].ToString(),
        Value1 = dr["Value1"].ToString(),
        Value1 = dr["Value1"].ToString(),
        Value1 = dr["Value1"].ToString(),
        Value1 = dr["Value1"].ToString(),
        Value1 = dr["Value1"].ToString(),
        Value1 = dr["Value1"].ToString(),
        Value1 = dr["Value1"].ToString(),
        Value1 = dr["Value1"].ToString()
};
```

Now using the keyboard (down arrow, delete etc) I change each row from 2 through 10. The problem I am having is that as soon as I delete the number 1 IntelliSense pops up with the possible values and the arrow keys are focused on that box.

I get the same in SQL and I have tried putting deliberate mistakes in the code hoping IntelliSense wont know what I am doing but that doesn't always stop it.

Is there anyway I can prevent it when I don't want it?

Comment: Have you tried using `Esc` to dismiss the intelisence popup?

Comment: @RowlandShaw yes and that does close IntelliSense but its another keystroke at the wrong side of the keyboard.  I was hoping to stop it in the first place.